# Spark sql replace collect_list empty lists with null

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have below data in dataframe

```
+----------+--------------+-------------------+---------------+
|id        |mid           |ppp                |qq             |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+---------------+
|A         |4             |[{P}]              |null           |
|B         |4             |[{P}]              |null           |
|A         |4             |null               |[{P}]          |
|A         |4             |null               |[{Q}]          |
|C         |4             |null               |[{Q}]          |
|D         |4             |null               |[{Q}]          |
|A         |4             |null               |[{R}]          |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+---------------+
```

I have below code

```
String[] array = {"id", "mid", "ppp", "qq"};

List<String> columns = Arrays.asList(array)

Column[] columns  = columns
   .stream()
   .filter(field -> !field.equals("id") && !field.equals("mid"))
   .map(column ->  flatten(when(size(collect_list(column)).equalTo(0), null)
                .otherwise(collect_list(column)))
                .as(column))
   .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new Column[0]);

Dataset<Row> output =  df
        .groupBy(functions.col("id"), functions.col("mid"))
        .agg(columns[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(columns, 1, columns.length));
```

The above code produces groups by id and mid and then collect_list collects elements of ppp and qq into arrays in both columns.

Output :

```
+----------+--------------+-------------------+----------------+
|id        |mid           | ppp               |qq              |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+----------------+
|A         |4             |[[P]]              |[[R], [P], [Q]] |
|B         |4             |null               |[[Q]]           |
|C         |4             |[[P]]              |null            |
|D         |4             |null               |[[Q]]           |
```

Code works fine exactly as required where if collect_list creates empty list, I am replacing that by null.

Is there a way to avoid calling collect_list twice in `when` and `otherwise` and achieve the same result that if collect_list creates empty list, replace that by null.

Answer (score 0):

of course you can do that, just call `size` on the array on set it to null if it is 0, something like

```
df
.groupBy()
.agg(
    collect_list($"mycol").as("arr_mycol")
 )
// set empty arrays to null
.withColumn("arr_mycol",when(size($"arr_mycol")>0,$"arr_mycol"))
```

Comment: i think solution is workable. One problem i have is that I can have any number of columns (ppp and qq are two columns) in my dataset and i prefer not touching the query for every column i may add in future. With withColumn I will have to add withColumn for every new column thats added. So is there a generic solution for any number of columns?